# Como deixar a média em vermelho?

Tags: php, condição

Como faço para o resultado da média ficar vermelho, caso o valor dela seja menor que 20?

Segue o código:

```
<?php
  function media($p1,$p2,$p3) {
    $resultado = ($p1 + $p2 + $p3)/3;
    return $resultado;
  }

  $aluno[0]["nome"] = "Ryan";
  $aluno[0]["media"] = media(10,20,30);

  $aluno[1]["nome"] = "Mikhaela";
  $aluno[1]["media"] = media(40,50,60);

  for($i=0;$i<count($aluno);$i++){
    echo "<b> Nome do Aluno </b>".$aluno[$i]["nome"]."<br>";
    echo "<b> A media do Aluno e </b>".$aluno[$i]["media"]."<br><br>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu adicionaria uma classe de CSS que seria introduzida no php.

Por exemplo:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($aluno);$i++){
    $media = $aluno[$i]["media"];
    $notaVermelha = '';
    if($media < 20){$notaVermelha = "notaVermelha"}

    echo "<b> Nome do Aluno </b>" .$aluno[$i]["nome"]."<br>";
    echo "<b> A media do Aluno e </b><span class='".$notaVermelha."'>".$media."</span>";
}
```

E no CSS:

```
.notaVermelha{
    color: "#F00";
}
```

Comment: Creio que seria melhor adicionar o elemento span somente no caso da nota ser realmente vermelha, e não só mudar o atributo (a não ser que fosse um atributo para azul e um para a vermelha).

Comment: @Bacco, obrigado pela suggestão. Eu prefiro assim, para ser consistente. Assim todos os valores têm o mesmo "wrapper" e se fôr preciso selecioná-los com javascript é mais fácil usar o `span` para os alcançar.

Answer (score 4):

Basta testar se a média é menor que 20 antes de por na tela.

```
if($aluno[$i]["media"] < 20){
    echo "<span style=\"color:red\"><b> A media do Aluno e </b></span>" .$aluno[$i]["media"]."<br><br>";
}else{
    echo "<b> A media do Aluno e </b>" .$aluno[$i]["media"]."<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: Note que faltam `'` para não quebrar o codigo à volta do style.

Comment: Ops, corrigido!

Answer (score 3):

Basta adicionar um if dentro do for

```
$resultado = '';
for($i=0;$i<count($aluno);$i++){
    $cor = 'black';
    if($aluno[$i]['media'] <= 20 ){
        $cor = 'red';
    }
    $resultado .=  "<p style='color:$cor;'><b> A media do Aluno e </b>"
    .$aluno[$i]["media"]."<br></P>";
}

echo $resultado;
```

Comment: Amigo Obrigado pela ajuda, obrigado mesmo! Muito bacana o esboço vou utilizar esse raciocínio!

Answer (score 2):

É só usar o `if`.

```
$aluno[0]["nome"] = "Ryan";
$aluno[0]["media"] = media(10,20,30);

$aluno[1]["nome"] = "Mikhaela";
$aluno[1]["media"] = media(40,50,60);


for($i=0;$i<count($aluno);$i++) {
    echo "<b> Nome do Aluno </b>" .$aluno[$i]["nome"]."<br>";
    if($aluno[$i]["media"] < 20) {
        echo "<font color=\"red\"><b> A media do Aluno e </b>" .$aluno[$i]["media"]."</font><br><br>";
    } else {
        echo "<b> A media do Aluno e </b>" .$aluno[$i]["media"]."<br><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Lembrando que o uso da tag ```<font>``` não é recomendado, visto que a mesma está deprecada a partir do HTML4.01 **e o HTML5 não mais suporta essa tag**. O ideal é utilizar CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode atribuir uma classe no "b" e pelo css formatar com a cor desejada. Neste caso toda a linha ficará vermelha. Se quiser só o resultado da média em vermelho mesmo pode fazer isso.

```
echo "<b> A media do Aluno e <span style='color: red;'>".$aluno[$i]["media]."</span><b><br>";
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Amigo ajudou sim cara, eu vou usar outro método mas o seu modo apenas pro resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizei a forma resumido do `if` para o código ficar mais seco.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($alunos); $i++){
    $alunos[$i]["media"] <= 5?$cor='red':$cor='blue';
    echo "<b>Nome do Aluno: </b>".$alunos[$i]["nome"]."<br>";
    echo "<p style='color:$cor;'><b>Media final: </b>".$alunos[$i]["media"]."<br><br></p>";
}
```